# SeaweedFS EC and cold data

Tags: storage, erasure-code, seaweedfs

During testing seaweedfs, questions began to appear. Can you explain me, what is hot, warm and cold data in seaweedfs logic?
And second question about erasurecoding: does it work only with warm data? Cannot I use it for hot or cold? If I don't have any type of replication, can I be sure, that all the data is safety stored?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SeaweedFS has two tiers, hot and warm. Warm are files changed not so often, but still need fast read.

The erasure coding works only with warm data. For hot data, replication is needed. Hot data needs fast write speed, which erasure coding can not really do it fast.

Comment: Is it possible to enable replication only for hot data to satisfy redundancy needs and rely on erasure coding (without replication) for warm data?

Comment: @TomRaganowicz it is designed the same way as you described.